# import error : No module named Django Windows

Tags: python, django, python-import

I just installed django by using git. Then I opened Python and run the command that imports django, now it's showing the error: `ImportError`.

My django is located at: `C:\Users\Alvin Varghese\django`.
I have set the PATH for python.

Comment: I think i installed it. I run the code in the git.!! it downloaded around 100 MB file. how to install it.?? no need right.??

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/install/

Comment: I already followed that. can you tell me what is my error.??

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Up to which step in the instructions have you gotten without error?

Comment: Dowloading complete the Django.!! Now i have to import it for checking.... but when i put import Django.. it shows up error

Comment: @AlvinVarghese So you did all three steps here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/install/#installing-development-version ?

Comment: When you have installed django successful, you can find the django files into python install directory (i.e. C:\Python-VERSION\). So If you are getting that error, and you are sure you are setted the path correctly, then you are not installed django yet!.

Comment: Also,you can try go to django home page inteast of github! or install using pip.